# Counting poles and zeros of a rational function

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Why is this true?

Take $$\frac{(z-5)^8}{(z-4)^{22} }$$

Then the only zeros it has is $5,\infty$. Where are the other 20? Is the text saying that the sum of the orders of the zeros is the maximum of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Don't forget the multiplicities of the zeros you found. One of those two zeros has multiplicity $8$ the other has multiplicity $14$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen why does multiplicity matter there are only two zeros. Saying that you have 8 5's and 17 $\infty$'s is redudent.

Comment: That way you get to the correct total of $22$. It's the same business as with polynomials. We want to say that every cubic has three zeros, but for that to be true we need to count them with multiplicities. And, read further, the multiplicity of a zero (or a pole) shows in the local behavior of the rational function.

Comment: "why does multiplicity matter there" because that makes exceptions like the one you found become non-exceptions, without breaking anything.